# EntLib Custom Validation Provider Example

Tags: validation, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

I have already tried to build a **Custom Validation Provider** to use with **EntLib. 6 Configuration Console** in Full-Integration Mode. I followed this [MSDN article: Creating a Custom Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664483%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).

All available examples I have seen provide basic integration or attribute-based validation. I am looking for a full implemented example.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is quite late at this point. Anyone working on this, can check these out:

http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/03/extending-enterprise-library-entlib.html
http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/03/extending-entlib-vab-part-1-enable.html
http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/04/extending-entlib-vab-part-21-create.html
http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/04/extending-entlib-vab-part-22-enable.html